# How to remove Ubuntu SDK click target (failed one)

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk

I was trying to create click target for `i386` architecture with `15.04 vivid` API. But it always fails at the end. I have retried it few times with no success. So, ok, I'm using `armhf` one.

But! After those tries, free disk space on my computer decreased for `1.3GB`. It looks like Ubuntu SDK did no cleanup at all.

So, does anybody know where Ubuntu SDK stores those targets? Or can I somehow reset all Ubuntu SDK related staff?

Answer (score 2):

here i am just giving example related to 15.04-armhf you can specify which you want to remove 
First run this

`sudo click unregister --user=phablet click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf`

if its not working then you can remove directly from

```
rm -rf /etc/schroot/chroot.d/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf
rm -rf /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf
```

then you can create from Tool>Options>ubuntu

other wise you can create via commandline

```
sudo click chroot -a armhf -f ubuntu-sdk-15.04 create
```

-a is architechture and -f is framework.